# Are affine SDEs invertible?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-calculus

If we have an a process $X_t$ with values in $\mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ which solves a **linear** Stratonovich SDE
$$
dX_t = A_t X_t dt + B_t X_t \circ dW_t
$$
then the inverse of $X_t$ exists and solves
$$
dZ_t = - Z_t A_t dt - Z_t B_t \circ dW_t
$$
It is easy to see that $X_tZ_t =$ Id by using the product rule. My question is this:

If $X$ instead solves the **affine** SDE
$$
dX_t = (A_t X_t + a_t) dt + (B_t X_t + b_t) \circ dW_t
$$
does it have an inverse?

Comment: @ mathman : I guess you have to (at least formally), calculate $d(1/X_t)$ using multidimensional Itô's lemma and check under what conditions the result holds true. Best regards

Comment: @TheBridge : What is $1/X_t$ if $X_t$ is a matrix?

Comment: even in 1d , with b fixed and non zero this process will *always* hit zero.  When $X_t$ gets small it looks like an ordinary brownian motion.

Comment: @mike : In 1-d this is a geometric Brownian motion, so does not hit zero.

Comment: not when you add a constant to the volatility. that's $b_t$ (little b) that should be non-zero.

Comment: @mike : Sorry, I see what you are saying now. Do you have a reference for proving that say $X_t = x + \int_0^t a_s ds + \int_0^t b_s dW_s$ hits zero a.s.?

Comment: almost any place that discusses the scale function, Breiman's probability book,   Freedman's Brownian Motion & diffusion, Karlin & Taylor A second course in ...